# implementing admob to an application via engineering reverse

Tags: admob, reverse, apktool

I would like to know how to implement admob banner ads and interstitial ads to an android application via engineering reverse (Apktool)
I've tried to convert smali files to java but no way.
too many errors and it doesn't work.
 Does someone has already worked on this? 
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to add this to an apk already compiled with apktool. it containts smali files.

Comment: Why don't you have the source to the app? It sounds like you hacking someone else's app.

Answer (score 0):

put the java  line related to the ads sdk for example admob to any eclipse project,then compile your app and decompile it so you will get these line in smali langage , so you can put them in the decompiled app where you want to put ads. i guess you need to also copy the folders in the lib folder

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for responding me.
i will clarify more my case is, i'm not having java files to use them with eclipse or android studio.
How can i use eclipse even my files are smali and they are compile by apktool.

Answer (score -1):

i meant you need to create java code or sample on eeclipse and make an app of it then decompile and use the smali code you get their , but it somehow very difficult .
another solution is to use this site enhance.co , they do what you are looking for but with limitation about when ads show up and kind of ads to show up